Enviar un mensaje desde una Apex Class hacia un Einstein Bot de Salesforce
El problema que me estoy encontrando es que necesito poder mostrar un mensaje predeterminado desde una clase Apex pero de una forma externa, debería ser directo a Whatsapp ya que tiene que ser algo global para todos los diálogos si se cumplen ciertas condiciones. No es posible usar una ApexAction en el bot porque tendría que hacer eso en cada diálogo y el bot es muy extenso.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
